# Does the size of a hydrogen atom (in its ground state) change when placed between the plates involved in the Casimir effect?

Tags: atomic-physics, vacuum, casimir-effect

Between the plates corresponding to the [Casimir effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect), there is a negative vacuum energy (setting the "free" vacuum energy to zero). Now the vacuum energy is responsible for the stability of the ground state of the hydrogen atom (see for example [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/s40509-015-0055-5)).

Will the size of the hydrogen atom in its ground state change because of this? It seems to me that because there are fewer interactions with the vacuum (simply because there are fewer modes) that the new "equilibrium" state will occupy a bigger volume, so the number of interactions with the vacuum increases. Which would mean that the size increases.

Comment: Vacuum energy is responsible for the stability of the ground state of Hydrogen? I'd be really interested in reading more about this. The link unfortunately does not work.

Comment: Since the Casimir effect and the Lamb shift are related, and the Lamb shift certainly affects orbitals: I will offer a qualitative "yes".